# spyder IDE - make variable explorer to follow the color scheme of the Editor

Tags: python, ide, spyder, color-scheme

I do not know why but when I change the color scheme of the spyder editor (I have the latest version installed and I do it through *preferences -> syntax coloring*), the variable explorer's color remains the same:

[image]

Since this is very distracting for me I searched it and found something more like a package called `QDarkStylesheet` that you can install and import, but it sounds a little tricky as I figured some people have reported several issues with it in GitHub! So, is there a straightforward way for making the variable explorer have the same dark color in spyder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Right now (May/2018) is not possible to make the coloring shown in the Variable Explorer follow the one in the Editor and IPython console.

However, we're working to make this possible for Spyder 4 (to be released in 2019).

Comment: thanks for your reaponse! So that ‘QDarkStylesheet’ thing is not gonna work either?

Comment: also how is the coloring shown in the variable explorer following the one in the editor in this picture: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3627835/9843057/32ab099c-5a7c-11e5-8159-38d8de4f3d7d.png

Comment: you know there are several discussions on this issue in the GitHub. Are you saying none of these works for the latest version of spyder?

Comment: All current solutions (based on QDarkStyleSheet) are workarounds and hacks from users and not supported by us officially. They work, but they don't interact too well with our current icon theme, among other limitations.